# Confusion related to the derivation of a dual of a problem

Tags: optimization, covariance, lasso, convergence

I have this confusion related to the derivation of the dual. I was referring to these lecture slides. I didn't get how the dual was derived.

I didn't get how the dual was derived. I am ok up to the part where the matrix C is replaced by C' and C'' to convert the non smooth part to the smooth part. However, I am getting confused from the part where the dual is derived.

When the lagrangian function is derived, it's written as $U.* C'$ and $V .* C''$. Does this come from the positive definiteness constraint i.e C'-C'' > 0. I didn't get which trick was used to get it.

Further I have questions that even after the lagrangian function is written there are constraints C' > 0 and C'' > 0. I am not sure when you get the lagrangian function you are supposed to get rid of constraints involving the primal variables isn't it?

I am kind of lost. After that it maximizes with respect to the primal variables C' and C''. I am ok with that. But after that I am finding it difficult to understand how the ultimate dual was obtained.

Can anyone please provide some suggestions?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that some important things are missing...

Comment: @Imorin. I have included everything from the slides